# WSO2 Gadget server

Tags: wso2

I'm evaluating WSO2 platform for further use.
I appreciate a lot this platform's techinacl pillars.
I see that links to Gadegt Server in WSO2 site redirect to User Engagement Server.
Does it mean that Gadget Server will be closed and subsituted by User Engagement Server?

Thanks a lot for your attention.
Pino

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WSO2 Gadget Server is deprecated now. That's why Gadget Server links are redirected to WSO2 User Engagement Server. WSO2 UES is a successor to Gadget Server.

You can check out [WSO2 User Engagement Server](http://wso2.com/products/user-engagement-server) and check docs [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/UES100/WSO2+User+Engagement+Server+1.0.0+Documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Find the story behind WSO2 UES here[1].

[1] http://www.nuwanbando.com/2013/07/wso2-user-engagement-server/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But User Engagement Server (UES) conceptually different from Gadget Server (GS). In Gadget Server is was all about gadgets, that has Google Gadget API. But in UES is more on the user experience but not about Gadgets. There the web developer can write a Gadget or a micro site with [Jaggery](http://jaggeryjs.org/) language (which is a server side JavaScript language) with the same UES dashboard and store them. Another user can search and publish them on their dashboard or a site.

Comment: I found a link to WSO2 Gadget Server GS : http://wso2.com/more-downloads/gadget-server, i thought it was deprecated.

Comment: You can download released versions of GS but will not be released with name GS in future. UES will be there instead which will have more than the features in GS.