# Does WSO2 combined WSO2 Gadget Server into WSO2 User Engagement Server?

Tags: wso2

Each time i want to download WSO2 Gadget Server i'm redirected to the download page of WSO2 User Engagement Server, are we talking about the same WSO2 product or WSO2 have decided to combine WSO2 Gadget Server into WSO2 User Engagement Server ?

Thanks.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148304/wso2-gadget-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember being confused about this as well when I went to download the Gadget Server on a new dev machine and couldn't find a link to it. Eventually I ran across the link below that explained how the WSO2 Gadget Server evolved into UES.

http://www.nuwanbando.com/2013/07/wso2-user-engagement-server/